# How to install gns3 on Debian 12?

Tags: debian, gns3

***Does anyone know how to install Gns3 on Debian 12?***

I have not been able to install it

alvandro@diego:~$ gns3
Please install the PyQt5.QtSvg module

I tried several ways to install it and couldn't.

agradeceria de su ayuda si saben como solucionarlo :/

Comment: what several ways did you try? ... did you read the error message?

Answer (score 1):

gns3 source packages on debian seems to be broken (you can run "sudo apt search gns3" to verify it) so you're only way to have gns3 on debian bookworm is to install it over PyPi packages and activate it using python virtual environment, take look at the part installing from PyPi in [https://docs.gns3.com/docs/getting-started/installation/linux](https://docs.gns3.com/docs/getting-started/installation/linux/)/.
You can also explore installation options on docker.
If nothing works for you take a look at eve-ng it's a powerful simulator like gns3, with a free version.